# Assign Function to other class variable

Tags: swift

Sorry for if this asked many times, I tried many solution none of the work for me. I am doing a very basic thing like this way.

```
class NotificationModel: NSObject {
   var selector = (() -> Void).self
}
```

Other class.

```
class TestNotificationClass1 {
   init() {
      var model = NotificationModel.init()
      model.selector = handleNotification //error is here
   }

   func handleNotification() -> Void {
    print("handle function 1")
   }
}
```

Error description: **Cannot assign value of type '() -> Void' to type '(() -> Void).Type'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `selector` to be able to hold any function with no parameters and no return value then change its declaration to:

```
var selector: (() -> Void)?
```

This also makes it optional. If you don't want it to be optional then you need to add an initializer to `NotificationModel` that takes the desired selector as a parameter as shown below:

```
class NotificationModel: NSObject {
    var selector: (() -> Void)

    init(selector: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.selector = selector

        super.init()
    }
}

class TestNotificationClass1 {
    init() {
        var model = NotificationModel(selector: handleNotification)
    }

    func handleNotification() -> Void {
        print("handle function 1")
    }
}
```